# Chrome Extension: trouble filling in a form field in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension that fills out a form and then submits it. I'm having trouble filling in a field, and I suspect it's because the state isn't being set correctly. Here's the code I wrote for it:

```
const el = document.getElementById(':r21:');
el.value = 12;
const eventNames = ['change', 'input', 'blur', 'focus', 'keyup', 'keydown', 'keypress'];
eventNames.forEach(eventName => {
  const event = new Event(eventName, { bubbles: true });
  el.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

Even though I'm setting the value for the input field, it doesn't seem to change. I think this might be because the state isn't being set correctly. Do you have any solutions or suggestions for how I can fill in this field's value?

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).